# Grails 3.0.9 send mail and AsynchronousMail

Tags: grails, grails-3.0, grails-3.0.9

I have a problem.

I want add to **Grails 3.0.9 AsynchronousMail**:

```
compile 'org.grails.plugins:asynchronous-mail:1.2'
```

Gradle probably installing this plugin, just do not see him...

Can anyone succeed such a configuration?

Help me.

Answer (score 1):

Just include this in your build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.grails.plugins:asynchronous-mail:2.0.0.RC2'
}
```

There's good documentation here  http://grails.org/plugin/asynchronous-mail

Go into your project directory.  Let's say it's at $HOME/projects/myproj.  Run the installer script for the plugin to initially create the config file:

```
cd $HOME/projects/myproj
grails install-asynchronous-mail-config
```

Now, edit $HOME/projects/myproj/grails-app/conf/DefaultAsynchronousMailConfig.groovy

The initial default values should be enough to get you started.

Good luck!